# AMAZON s3- I'm able to successfully upload images to s3 bucket but can't view them

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

When I put in the link to the url I get this message

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>5E3C0EC6695332F6</RequestId>
<HostId>
+oAnihC+lgFxkMu5L9aUURaU/9ufCSWD0e/h4rn+LQhAp6CJox1yNJH1ojaGVvktJ0xbD7vx10=
</HostId>
</Error>
```

This is what my bucket policy looks like

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy000000000",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt--someNumbers--",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucketname/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I also checked off all permissions access for 'Any authenticated AWS'

**update** my php code

```
private function fillMedia($media, $user, $file, $key)
{
    if($media->category =='profile'){
        $source_file=$file->dirname .'/' . $file->basename;
    }else{
        $source_file = $file->getRealPath();
    }
    $s3 = AWS::createClient('s3');
    $result = $s3->putObject(array(
        'Bucket' => env('BUCKET_NAME'),
        'Key' => $user->id . '/'. $media->category .'/'. $key,
        'SourceFile' => $source_file,
        'Metadata' => array(
        'Owner' => $user->first_name .' ' . $user->last_name
        )
        ));
}
```

Comment: uploading via php.  I have another bucket using the same source code that works fine, so I don't think it's my php code.

Answer (score 2):

I confirmed that I could access using this bucket policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::name-of-your-bucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here are the steps that I performed:

Step 1 - Create a S3 bucket.

Step 2 - Select the bucket and then choose Properties

Step 3 - Click "Add Bucket Policy" and insert the code snippet above. Make sure to change ***name-of-your-bucket*** to your bucket name.

Step 4 - Upload a test file to the bucket and select the file.

Step 5 - Choose Properties for the uploaded file - there will be an URL similar to https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/***name-of-your-bucket***/***your-test-file-name.jpg***

Step 6 - Use the URL above to open the test file.

When I removed the bucket policy that I used, I received the same error as you.

I hope this helps!

Comment: okay i made a silly mistake.  my url was wrong o_o.  Thanks for you help

Comment: Excellent! Glad I could help!

Comment: I'm new to AWS. Your answer helped me. Could you give a link to some simple and useful explanation about why policy is needed, the meaning of each line and how do I know what to write in each line? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Its works for me

```
$s3 = new S3("awsAccessKey", "awsSecretKey");
    $s3->putObjectFile(source, "bucket-name", destination, S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ));
```

Answer (score 0):

For the above bucket policy we need to provide credentials on wp-config.php or without credential we can use the policy.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).